# converting a binary raw image data in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, firebreath

I'm using a firebreath plugin and I am sending a raw binary image data from the plugin to JavaScript, but was not able to use this data as JavaScript did not recognize this. I later converted the raw image data to base64 format and used in JavaScript in which case I was able to draw the image but performance was hit as base64 conversion took nearly 100ms for each conversion.
Is there a way where in I can draw image directly from the raw image? I Basically have to improve performance.

Comment: What plugin? What kind of data is JS receiving? How are you converting it to base64? How are you "drawing" the image?

Please provide more information in your question (also: your code!). We can't help you if we don't know what you're doing, __exactly__.

Comment: image1.src = "data:image/bmp;base64,"+btoa(image.header)+buff;

Comment: in case of base64 this is how i am drawing, i am using a npapi plugin and the raw image data is basically in the binary format

Comment: @user3365783 You *can* do images without base64-encoding them... but you need to url-encode them instead ;) Either way, you're converting!

Comment: where buff is the base64 converted image data, i add a bmp header and draw it on a canvas

Comment: @ Niet the Dark Absol is there a way without encoding or any faster encoding techniques. what is url-encode btw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rather than drawing it on a canvas, you could try putting a data URI in an image tag and sending it as a jpeg.  Basically compress the image as much as you reasonably (for your application) can before you send it to javascript in order to minimize the amount you need to convert w/ base64.  The only other way I could see it maybe working would be to use a websocket to talk to the plugin, which has its own problems.